# Sum of consecutive elements in C

Tags: c

For example my array is `arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`

I want the sum of consecutive elements seperately like this

```
sum = 3 (1+2)
sum = 5 (2+3)
sum = 7 (3+4)
sum = 9 (4+5)
```

How do I approach this?

As someone is voting to close this question because no effort shown, here's what I tried before asking this question (I used scanf but this above array was just an example).

```
int n, arr[10], i, j = i+1, sum = 0;
scanf("%d", &n);
for(i = 0; i<n; i++)
{
    scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    sum = arr[i] + arr[j];
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Look into using `for` loops.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are the consecutive elements always from 1 to n ? Do you have to find consecutive elements first because the array may have non consecutive elements ? I suggest you try to think about what the input and output should look like first, then try to find an approach.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no effort shown

Comment: Will you only ever need to sum two consecutive elements, or might you need to go to 3, 4 or more (on bigger data arrays)?  If you may need to go for bigger, you need to look at running totals (running averages).  For just 2 or 3 items in a row, do it from first principles — add two items, or add three items, per iteration.  With sizes of 4 or more, you can save operations by using running total techniques, and the bigger the run length, the more you can save.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    for (int i = 1; i < sizeof arr/sizeof *arr; i++){
        printf("%d + %d = % d\n", arr[i-1], arr[i], (arr[i-1]+arr[i]));
    }
}
```

You can always of course format the `printf()` to show output as desired.

Comment: How about `for (int i = 1; i < sizeof arr/sizeof *arr; i++)` ... `arr[i-1]+arr[i]`? (you always protect against reading outside of the array bounds that way)

Comment: I did the same thing but I declared `j = i+1` then `sum = arr[i]+arr[j]` (I used scanf for the array) but it didn't work. Now when I used `sum = arr[i]+arr[i+1]`, it worked!
Why is it so?

Comment: Thanks @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: Sure, I voted for you, but you should consider `arr[]` instead of the `arr[5]` declaration. Why? There is just too much risk of mistake by being off by `1` when the initialization contains more and more elements. Just let the compiler do its job and declare `int arr[] = { ...... }`; Also, you will more rabidly increase your programming skills if you compile with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` in your compile string (`gcc`) or `/Wall` (for `cl.exe` -- i.e. VS) and do not accept code until it compiles without warning `:)` You can learn a lot just by letting your compiler help.

Comment: Oh, I can change it, the only reason I had left it as such was because initial question was with it.

Comment: And part of that is my fault, I should have suggested `for (size_t i = 1; i < sizeof arr/sizeof *arr; i++)` as the return of `sizeof` is an unsigned number and technically `int i` will then prompt a *warning* for comparison between *signed and unsigned* values. It should be `size_t` anyway as `size_t` is often an `8-byte` value representing the positive values of `long` (or `long long` on x86) providing a greater range.

Comment: @Annabelle, not need to change as long as you explain. Part of the role of answering questions on S.O. is stepping into the role of *teacher*. You always want to try and pass on as much correct information as possible to help those coming along behind you in coding `:)`

Comment: Okay, makes sense. Thanks for the insights!

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to go about summing adjacent elements in the array. One way, that protects against the possibility of reading beyond the end of the array, is to start your iteration at `1` and sum `array[i-1] + array[i]`. For example, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    for (size_t i = 1; i < sizeof arr/sizeof *arr; i++)
        printf ("sum %d = (%d + %d)\n", arr[i-1]+arr[i], arr[i-1], arr[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/arrsum
sum 3 = (1 + 2)
sum 5 = (2 + 3)
sum 7 = (3 + 4)
sum 9 = (4 + 5)
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.